# pyside6-designer - libpython3.12.dylib (no such file)

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyside6

I want to start pyside6-designer after I installed Python 3.12.1 via pyenv, which was successful. I also installed pyside6 via pip, which also was successful.

Now, when I want to start the designer with `pyside6-designer`, I get this error:

```
Error: dyld[28253]: terminating because inserted dylib 'libpython3.12.dylib' could not be loaded: tried: 'libpython3.12.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibpython3.12.dylib' (no such file), 'libpython3.12.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/xxx123/libpython3.12.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/xxx123/libpython3.12.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/xxx123/libpython3.12.dylib' (no such file)
dyld[28253]: tried: 'libpython3.12.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibpython3.12.dylib' (no such file), 'libpython3.12.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/xxx123/libpython3.12.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/xxx123/libpython3.12.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/xxx123/libpython3.12.dylib' (no such file)

while executing '/Users/xxx123/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PySide6/Designer.app/Contents/MacOS/Designer'
```

I am running Mac OSX 14.2.1 (23C71).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem on OSX
`cd */python3.11/site-packages/PySide6/` where you installed pyside and then use `open Designer.app/` and you will launch the app

Answer (score 0):

Shotgun approach:

You need to either set the path information (which with pyenv is not desired as the whole idea is to be able to switch at will) or copy the lib from the `.pyenv/versions/3.xx/lib` folder to where you run pyside6-designer, etc. or to one of the paths you see where it tried to find it.

This is not a real solution IMHO.

Comment: Could you be more specific?